# Ayuda con un for o .each en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola a todos mi duda es la siguiente tengo un input que pueden ser 1 a N depende del forech del php y con ese PHP le pongo el nombre y el ID, en mi JS lo que quiero es saber su su ID de cada uno osea si me trae uno, capturar el ID del input y asi si me trae N,
por el momento solo me trae el ID del primero y para saber eso este es el codigo creo que para saber de los N id seria un for pero no se como construirlo
GRACIAS.

```
var hola = $(".numeros").attr("id");
alert(hola);
```

Este es mi codigo php

```
<tr>
<td>Número de estudiantes del turno según SIAGIE</td>
<?php foreach ($niveles as $obj) { ?>
<td>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input class="form-control numeros" type="text" id="3_<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', $obj->nivel) . '_' . $obj->codigoModular; ?>"  name="3_<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', $obj->nivel) . '_' . $obj->codigoModular; ?>">
</div>
</div>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorre todos los elementos por una clase común a todos y pregunta la id:

```
$(".numeros").each(function() {
    var id = "#"+this.id;   
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: necesito ayuda, edite el post

Answer (score 1):

puedes recorrer los elementos del `DOM` con `.each()` de jQuery, para hacerlo primero hay que seleccionar que elementos van a ser seleccionados.

Si se seleccionan por clase, el selector de jQuery devolverá un arreglo con todos los elementos seleccionados `$('.clase')`.

Ahora solo queda aplicar el método `.each()` para recorrer los elementos por lo cual la función quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$('.numeros').each(function(index, elem) {
  //index: Posision del elemento actual de 0 - N.
  //elem: Elemento actual del DOM que esta seleccionado
  console.log($(elem).attr('id'));
});
```

Ejemplo: (Este es un ejemplo de los que aparentemente se podría ver en el navegador)

```js
$(function() {
  var arrIds = [];
  $('.numeros').each(function(index, elem) {
    console.log($(elem).attr('id'));
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control numeros" type="text" id="3_001" name="3_001">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control numeros" type="text" id="3_002" name="3_002">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control numeros" type="text" id="3_003" name="3_003">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control numeros" type="text" id="3_004" name="3_004">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Necesito ayuda, edite el post

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores te sugiero que abras una nueva pregunta y esta revertirla a como estaba la ultima vez cuando aceptaste la respuesta de Carmen, te digo esto ya que si respondo en base a tu modificación la respuestas que te han proporcionado dejaran de ser validas

Comment: Eso estoy haciendo gracias revisa la nueva pregunta porfa

Answer (score 0):

Te he dejado un pequeño ejemplo para que te orientes de como funciona y lo puedas ejecutar.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function tomarElementos(){
    var respuesta = "";
    var maximoElementos = $(".numeros").size();
    for(i = 0; i<maximoElementos; i++){
      respuesta = respuesta + "/" + $(".numeros:eq("+i+")").val();
    }
    alert(respuesta);
  }
  
</script>
<input class="numeros" type="text" id=""  name="" value="asd0">
<input class="numeros" type="text" id=""  name="" value="asd1">
<input class="numeros" type="text" id=""  name="" value="asd2">
<input class="numeros" type="text" id=""  name="" value="asd3">
<button onclick="tomarElementos()">clickme</button>
```

En tu caso particular es del siguiente modo:

```
<tr>
<td>Número de estudiantes del turno según SIAGIE</td>
<?php foreach ($niveles as $obj) { ?>
<td>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input class="form-control numeros" type="text" id="3_<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', $obj->nivel) . '_' . $obj->codigoModular; ?>"  name="3_<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', $obj->nivel) . '_' . $obj->codigoModular; ?>">
</div>
</div>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    var respuesta = ""; //Variable para salida
    var maximoElementos = $(".numeros").size(); //Define la cantidad de nodos con esta clase
    for(i = 0; i<maximoElementos; i++){ //recorre la n cantidad de nodos
      respuesta = respuesta + "/" + $(".numeros:eq("+i+")")attr("id"); //va asignando a respuesta, el dato anterior mas el valor del nuevo nodo
    }

    alert(respuesta); //Lanza el resultado del recorrido
</script>
```

Espero que puedas entenderlo y te sea de ayuda. Cualquier cosa hazmelo saber en los comentarios para ir orientándote.

Éxito en tu proyecto!

Comment: necesito ayuda, edite el post

Comment: no veo en que lo editaste, es exactamente lo mismo

Comment: Esta en una nueva pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68307/asignar-valor-a-inputs-usando-each?noredirect=1#comment124937_68307

Comment: la acabo de ver, de hecho te hice una pregunta